# C# synchronization between async tasks with infinite while loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I have one async task running an infinite loop doing some realtime processing:

```
private async void RealTimeProcessingAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //....
       Tmstaus  status = await ReadStatusAsync();
       switch (status)
       {
            case Ack:
            //...
            break;
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

And I created another async method SendWriteRqst that post command to RealTimeProcessingAsync(), should wait for status to set to defined condition and return.

```
public async Task<WriteState> SendWriteRqstAsync(TmCommand tmCmd)
{
    //...
    await SomeCondition()//based on status value
    //...
    return wrState;
}
```

It will works if SomeCondition() runs another while loop to polling status and return true if conditions set, but I'm looking for better solution.

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: What is `SomeCondition()` doing, polling status from where/what?

Comment: Actually it's a task that polls conditions of  some variables from RealTimeProcessingAsync()  like status variable.

Comment: So `SomeCondition()` will call `RealTimeProcessingAsync()` but will only return if some conditions are met which depend on status changes made by `RealTimeProcessingAsync()`. That's why you have to call `RealTimeProcessingAsync()` multiple times. Is that it?

Comment: No ,RealTimeProcessingAsync() start when connection established to HardWare Board,I want to implement SendWriteRqstAsync asynchronous based on condition in RealTimeProcessingAsync() thats why I implement SomeCondition()

Comment: So... `RealTimeProcessingAsync()` is started at some point and runs forever? Then you want `SendWriteRqstAsync` to only return if some conditions are met within `RealTimeProcessingAsync()`. Did I get that right? Otherwise, can you post a bit of what `SomeCondition()` is doing?

Comment: I think I have an idea (and you won't need another loop), but I want to fully understand what is going on before posting an answer that helps you

Comment: Yes,RealTimeProcessingAsync() starts by user ,user can send request to HW by SendWriteRqstAsync that post command to RealTimeProcessingAsync() (using Queue) and HW return status and data to RealTimeProcessingAsync() again,
and I want to implement SendWriteRqstAsync that return based on condition from status and data HW gave back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It will works if SomeCondition() runs another while loop to polling status and return true if conditions set , but I'm looking for better solution.

What you want is a signal instead of a polling loop. If you only need to set the signal once, you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. If you want a signal that can be set and reset (without having to be reconstructed), then you can use [`AsyncManualResetEvent`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-1-asyncmanualresetevent/) (also [available from NuGet in my AsyncEx.Coordination library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination)).

Comment: "AsyncManualResetEvent" is what I need,Thank you for your answer and library it's very useful for me.